# How do you show that an improper Riemann integral is divergent?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

In specific, I'm supposed to decide whether the following integral exists, and if it does, to calculate its value:

$$\int_0^\infty  \frac{x\ln(x)}{\sinh(x)-x}dx.$$

After checking with Mathematica, I came to the conclusion that this integral does not exist. Furthermore, it appears that the integrand does not possess an elementary primitive.

Up until now, I only came across divergent integrals where one could calculate the primitive, and upon evaluating at the boundaries and taking the limit from t to c or infinity, one finds that the integral diverges.

Answer (score 2):

The integral converges "at infinity" but diverges "at zero".

As $x\to 0$, $\sinh x-x\sim x^3/6$ so
$$\frac{x\ln x}{\sinh x-x}\sim\frac{6\ln x}{x^2}$$
and the improper integral
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2}\,dx$$
diverges.

Comment: If $f\sim g$, we just get $f(x)\leq g(x)$ in a neigborhood of $0$... So, I don't really understand your conclusion.

Comment: @user659895: If $f\sim_a g$, then $$D|g(x)|\leq |f(x)|\leq C|g(x)|.$$ for some $C,D>0$ in a neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: Is it mathematically accurate to approximate the hyperbolic sine through the first two terms of its power series? I understand that it makes sense for arbitrarily small values of x though.